# How to stick a paragraph that has a background color with a button in css?

Tags: html, css

I do not want to have a space between `#id` and `.card button`.
[image]

i want to put `some texts` on top of the `buy` without that white space.how can i do that?

### css and html:

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  
}

.price {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 22px;

}

.card button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.card button:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#id{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<body>
     
    <div class='card'>
        <h1>product</h1>
        <p class="price">$price</p>
        <p id="id">some texts.</p>
        <p><button>buy</button></p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use `<p>` for elements that aren't a paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove padding and margin of `p` like in below example using a class `.no-space`. This is because by default `p` element will have some padding and margin.

[image]

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  
}

.price {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 22px;

}

.card button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.card button:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.no-space {
 padding-bottom:0;
 margin-bottom:0;
  padding-top:0;
 margin-top:0;
}

#id{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<body>
     
    <div class='card'>
        <h1>product</h1>
        <p class="price">$price</p>
        <p class="no-space" id="id">some texts.</p>
        <p class="no-space"><button>buy</button></p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is no reason to wrap the `button`-element inside a `p`-element. It is semantically incorrect.

All `p`-elements have, by default, the following styling:

`margin-top: 1em;` `margin-bottom: 1em;` `margin-left: 0;` `margin-right: 0;`

You can remove the space by setting the `margin-bottom` to `0` on the`#id`-element:

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  
}

.price {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 22px;

}

.card button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.card button:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#id{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<body>
     
    <div class='card'>
        <h1>product</h1>
        <p class="price">$price</p>
        <p id="id">some texts.</p>
        <button>buy</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `margin: 0` to the style declaration of `#id` selector in your css file as an easy fix.

```
#id {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    margin: 0; // add this line
}
```

**Detailed answer:**
If you look at the dimensions of the paragraph tag in the Developer Console, you would find that it is taking 16px margin on top and bottom.

[image]

By default, the left and right margins of a text element are set to 0 , but they all come with a margin-top and margin-bottom. You get the desired layout if override this default `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to 0.